# track 2D offset after rotation

Tags: mathematics, rotation, transformation

red is my origin point, blue is my offset, both are 2D vectors, how can calculate blue after rotation?

this is the code I've been trying(just throwing things against a wall to see what sticks)

```
public static Vector2F CalcPointWithRotation(Vector2F origin, Vector2F point, float rotation)
{
    return new Vector2F((float)Math.Cos(rotation) * origin.x, (float)Math.Sin(rotation) * origin.y);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `rotation` variable is an angle in radians around your object's `origin` point, and your `point` variable is an offset vector relative to the origin in the object's local coordinate space, then this is simply:

```
public static Vector2F CalcPointWithRotation(Vector2F origin, Vector2F point, float rotation)
{
    float c = (float)Math.Cos(rotation);
    float s = (float)Math.Sin(rotation);

    return new Vector2F(
                        origin.x + c * point.x - s * point.y,
                        origin.y + s * point.x + c * point.y,
    );
}
```

You may recognize this as a matrix multiplication:

$$\vec p ^\prime = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta &-\sin\theta\\\sin \theta &  cos\theta \end{bmatrix}\vec p + \vec o$$

Or with a homogeneous matrix...

$$\begin{bmatrix}p^\prime_x \\ p^\prime_y \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta &-\sin\theta & o_x\\\sin \theta &  cos\theta 
 & o_y \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}p_x \\ p_y \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

When rotation is 0 (or 2 pi, 4 pi, etc.) then this just gives origin + point. As the rotation value increases, the offset from the origin swings around, tracing a circle around that point.

Comment: this seems to work fine on the X-axis but the Y-axis barely moves at all

Comment: My apologies, I went too fast and left out the second terms on each line. That should be better now. You can flip the signs on the two `s` terms if you want a positive angle to rotate in the opposite direction.